# UITextfield.text to UILabel.text

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

What I'm making is a `iPhone` application (Single View (Latest `XCode`)) that has a button a label and a `textfield`.

What i want to do is, let the user enter a name, then press the button and make the Label change to Hello {The name entered}.

I've searched around and not anything worked for me.

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", label.text, textField1.text]; // Didn't work.
```

I've made,`View2.h`and `View2.m`.
The code in it:

**View2.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface View2 : UIViewController
{

IBOutlet UILabel *HelloWorldLabel;
IBOutlet UITextField *NameText;
}

-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender;

@end
```

**View2.m**:

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{

}
```

EDIT1:

My Storyboard

[image]

Comment: Are your IBOutlets connected correctly in Interface Builder?

Comment: Can you be more specific then "Didn't work"?

Comment: @0x7fffffff it just showed nothing.
The label was empty after pressing the button

Comment: @user2947423 Can you show us the connections inspector in your screenshot? Go to the storyboard then press cmd+option+6, select view2 then take the screen shot.

Comment: @user2947423 Also the code above you are calling it `textField1` but then in the .h you are calling it `NameText`. Which is it?

Comment: @Vrasidas how do i actually do this, could you explain me?

Comment: Check where it says The Connections from this link: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection

Answer (score 2):

`HelloWorldLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", NameText.text];` should work okay.

Comment: His posted code should have also worked okay, so this is not the solution... he has a greater problem, I think his IBOutlets aren't hooked up properly or he is working across multiple UIViewControllers and didn't let us know about that.

Comment: This is a much better format though, otherwise when they press the button over and over his code would have made the string change AND GROW each time... longer and longer :) Haha!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
Now i get: [link](http://gyazo.com/146af3b27cda39f563464bb794814995)

My code:
[link](http://gyazo.com/63f4914e829eb8286ad9e2a8f66feb66)

Comment: Looking at the bottom image on your main question you want to click the far right icon on the right hand panel. It looks like an arrow inside a circle. This will show you what connections you have. Then you will know if your text controls and buttons are wired up correctly. Could you possibly post that image for us to see please?

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted had an empty `IBAction` method. If that is your actual code then of course nothing is happening. If it's not your actual code, then **POST YOUR ACTUAL CODE**. We can't help you debug something we can't see, and the devil is in the details.

Also, you should follow Cocoa naming conventions. Properties and instance method names should start with a lower case label, and the name should describe what it does.

Your *HelloWorldLabel* should be **helloWorldLabel**, and *NameText* should be **nameTextField**.

Post your entire `IBAction` method. Also add log statements to make sure your outlets are linked correctly:

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"helloWorldLabel field = %@. nameTextField = %@", helloWorldLabel, nameTextField);
  self.helloWorldLabelText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", nameTextField.text];
}
```

When you run the program, look at the log output when you click the button. If you don't see anything, your `IBAction` is not linked to the button. If the log statement shows `NULL` for either the `nameTextField` or the `helloWorldLabel` then those outlets are not connected properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender{
   self.helloWorldLabelText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your text here"];
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't have been down-voted since he is trying to debug... This is a valid answer since the sample code above didn't have any code inside the button... however this also belongs in the comments since you are debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your button event

```
   NSString *str = nameText.text;
   HelloWorldLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Hello",str];
```

Comment: This should not have been down-voted, the sample code above had no code inside the button which could be the problem.

Comment: @user2947423 Please make sure you label and textField both connected in IB. Because you code should work fine, Though it may fail if you press the button more than once. That will add the current text of label and text field and place it to the label text. For me it seems you are facing a problem of making connection to the IB.

Comment: I get the same error as i replied above,
Hello (null)
[link](http://gyazo.com/146af3b27cda39f563464bb794814995)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)yourTextField {
    //when the user taps "return" on the keyboard of "yourTextField" it will update the label
    [self updateLabel];
    return NO;
}

- (void) updateLabel{
    //change your Label, "myLabel" to the text from "yourTextField"
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourTextField.text];
}
```

also, if you would like to make the keyboard go away when the user presses the `return` key, simply add the following code to your `textFieldShouldReturn:` method:

```
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

if you want to make this happen when the user presses a button, instead of the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method, you could use:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed{
    [self updateLabel];
}
```

Just make sure to assign the `buttonPressed` Action to when the button is pressed!

Also, make sure to declare both the Action `buttonPressed` (if your using it), and your UILabel `myLabel`.